# hp7410 mfd prints from computer ok, but no black when copying

Tags: printer

I have a hp 7410 multi function device used. When I print from the computer all colors and black comes out fine. But when I copy both from the glass and auto feeder anything in black does not print. in black mode, nothing. In color mode anything black does not print. Very odd siuation.
thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Try the HP Printer Diagnostic tools

http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&lc=en&lang=en&docname=c02073861